# Writing a values.yaml file for the Datadog Agent copies files into trace-agent directory etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d`

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, datadog

In my Kubernetes cluster I have launched the datadog agent via [helm charts](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts)

Ultimately in my trace-agent I want to copy some `.yaml` files into the `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d` directory.

I can accomplish on a single pod by running:

```
kubectl -n datadog -c trace-agent cp ./configs/bookie_conf.yaml datadog-ft6dq:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d
kubectl -n datadog -c trace-agent cp ./configs/broker_conf.yaml datadog-ft6dq:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d
kubectl -n datadog -c trace-agent cp ./configs/proxy_conf.yaml datadog-ft6dq:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d
kubectl -n datadog -c trace-agent cp ./configs/zookeeper_conf.yaml datadog-ft6dq:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d
```

But this is not elegant. I want to capture this logic in Terraform for all my datadog pods.

In  datadog's [`values.yaml`](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/datadog/values.yaml#L404) I can't tell how I specify a given path with a `confd` parameter.

They give the rough example:

```
  # datadog.confd -- Provide additional check configurations (static and Autodiscovery)

  ## Each key becomes a file in /conf.d
  ## ref: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/tree/main/Dockerfiles/agent#optional-volumes
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/autodiscovery/
  confd: {}
  #   redisdb.yaml: |-
  #     init_config:
  #     instances:
  #       - host: "name"
  #         port: "6379"
  #   kubernetes_state.yaml: |-
  #     ad_identifiers:
  #       - kube-state-metrics
  #     init_config:
  #     instances:
  #       - kube_state_url: http://%%host%%:8080/metrics

  # datadog.checksd -- Provide additional custom checks as python code
```

But It's not clear to me how to specify particular confd directory.

There is also a trace-agent parameter, but it doesn't have a confd subparameter as an option

### Resources

[OpenMetrics configuration directory](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/guide/agent-configuration-files/?tab=agentv6v7#agent-configuration-directory)

[sample openmetrics.d/conf.yaml](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/openmetrics/datadog_checks/openmetrics/data/conf.yaml.example)

Comment: Is this related to Prometheus in any way? Also, if not sensitive, can you add an example of the YML file you want to add in the `conf.d/openmetrics.d` directory?

Comment: @Marko E Here's the exact configs I want to copy in: https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-datadog/tree/master/configs. This approach isn't supposed to require a Prometheus server, but the metrics are produced in Prometheus data format.

Comment: I have no idea actually how to fix this, but does this make sense to check: https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/datadog/values.yaml#L618-L637?

Comment: Or alternatively, you could try adding a key `openmetrics.d/proxy_conf.yaml` followed by the content. Not sure that will work, but might be worth a try.